# Why does it keep on re-executing and returns the /favicon.ico as a url even though I just run the file once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I'm creating a server and trying to work with some of the methods under http. I ran npm start once but it executed the operation twice and the url I got in the second one is /favicon.ico. What is it and why it's appearing? Please check the link for the image.

[image: Please check image here]

Answer (score 1):

Favicon is short for favorite icon,is a file containing one or more small icons, associated with a particular website or web page. Browsers that provide favicon support typically display a page's favicon in the browser's address bar (sometimes in the history as well) and next to the page's name in a list of bookmarks. Browsers that support a tabbed document interface typically show a page's favicon next to the page's title on the tab, and site-specific browsers use the favicon as a desktop icon.

Generally Browsers look for favicon.ico in the website's root automatically.

Other ways to use/specify fav icons are listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use